# MySQLi speed: multiple queries or one

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get data from a database which looks like this:

```
id - brand - type
1    Airbus  plane
2    Boeing  plane
3    Fokker  plane
4    Toyota  car
5    Mustang car
6    Peugeot car
7    Sparta  bike
```

Now I want to e.g. output an `<hr/>` whenever the type is different. I can do this two ways:

- One prepared statement and set a variable `$current_type` and check its value with the one from the database
- Three prepared statements (for each type since they don't differ from plane, car, bike)

Which is the fastest? I would say the first but the second makes my code look so much better. Can I neglect the speed difference?

Comment: Use one query and handle the rest in your php logic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running a quick test to find out.

Comment: For small data like this: fetch, group-by (into a hierarchy using whatever is most convenient), iterate (multiple levels as per grouping), display. Using an ordering (over an index) can help deal with *very large* streaming (if supported) result sets and simpler grouping algorithm - but KISS.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is definitely faster, I'd much rather have an extra temporary variable in my PHP code than 2 extra queries. The difference might be neglegible in your case, but it isn't be something I would give up for slightly neater code.

Comment: I don't add two extra queries. I'd still have one but it runs multiple times cause its in an for loop. Thanks for the comment by the way.